# converts textview number to integer

Tags: android

I'm trying to increase and decrease number when I click "increase" and "decrease" button

I can see number is changing in textview but I need to use textview's number to make graph (I need integer value)

I trt to use

```
    String value= display.getText().toString();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

but it's not working

can you guys help me how to do get integer from this?

my code is

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
int numtest;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    numtest = 0;

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numtest = numtest + 1;
            display.setText(numtest + "");
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (numtest < 0){
                numtest =  0;
                display.setText(numtest+ "");
            }
            if (numtest > 0) {
                numtest = numtest - 1;
                display.setText(numtest+ "");
            }
        }
    });

    String value= display.getText().toString();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

this is my entire code

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {
int numtest;
int numgraph;
Button smoke_string, subtract_string;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    numtest = 0;
    smoke_string = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    subtract_string = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

    smoke_string.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numtest = numtest + 1;
            display.setText(numtest + "");
        }
    });

    subtract_string.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (numtest > 0) {
                numtest = numtest - 1;
                display.setText(numtest + "");
            }
            if (numtest < 0) {
                numtest = 0;
                display.setText(numtest + "");
            }
        }
    });



    String value= display.getText().toString();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(value);



    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Date d2 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Date d3 = calendar.getTime();

    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);


    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(d1, 3),
            new DataPoint(d2, 5),
            new DataPoint(d3, i)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);

    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(MainActivity2.this));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3); // only 4 because of the space

    graph.getViewport().setMinX(d1.getTime());
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(d3.getTime());
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why Do you want to this it that way,

You can do it this way,

```
List<Integer> graph = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numtest = numtest + 1;
            display.setText(numtest + "");
            graph.add(numtest);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (numtest < 0){
                numtest =  0;
                display.setText(numtest+ "");

            }
            if (numtest > 0) {
                numtest = numtest - 1;
                display.setText(numtest+ "");
            }
            graph.add(numtest);
        }
    });
```

This way you have the a number value for each click on the add and sub buttons.

Edit:

Try something like this,

```
     public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

        int numtest;
        int numgraph;
        Button smoke_string, subtract_string;
        TextView display;
        GraphView graph;

        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            numtest = 0;
            smoke_string = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            subtract_string = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
            graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

            smoke_string.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Date d = calendar.getTime();
                    numtest = numtest + 1;
                    display.setText(numtest + "");
                    series.add(new DataPoint(d,numtest));
                    redrawGraph();
                }
            });

            subtract_string.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Date d = calendar.getTime();
                    if (numtest > 0) {
                        numtest = numtest - 1;
                        display.setText(numtest + "");
                    }
                    if (numtest < 0) {
                        numtest = 0;
                        display.setText(numtest + "");
                    }
                    series.add(new DataPoint(d,numtest));
                    redrawGraph();
                }
            });

        }

        private void redrawGraph(){
            graph.addSeries(series);
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(MainActivity2.this));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3); // only 4 because of the space

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

            Date d1 = calendar.getTime();// Lower bound, This has to be dynamic

            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);//  Upper Bound
            Date d3 = calendar.getTime();

            graph.getViewport().setMinX(d1.getTime());
            graph.getViewport().setMaxX(d3.getTime());
            graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Thx for suggestion; however, when I try, it gives me error because I'm using "graph" value to creat graph by using graphview library. so I change  List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and i.add(numtest); when I try to use "i" as a integer in graph, it gives me error message cannot resolve constructor 'datapoint(java.util.list<java.lang.integer>)' can you tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: @vision can you add the code where you use to create the graph? and the relationship with the MainActivity2 class

Comment: @vision Do not add them ad comments, Add them to you question as an edit, and also add the Activity also not just the code snippets

Comment: Do you have another Activity class that run this graph code?. Or is it the same Activity class where you have the up  down buttons?

Comment: @vision This may not be the exact solution, But Every time you press the up or down button, you should redraw the graph